# Custom layout for a custom keypad

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I don't know if I'm doing it the wrong way but here's what I want to do :

I've designed a simple keypad with 12 buttons (3 columns, 4 rows) and I'd like to make it standard. I mean in any of my layouts I'd like to just write

```
<my.own.Keypad>
  ....
</my.own.Keypad>
```

And the Keypad take care of setting the 12 buttons and everything.

I think I have to extend an Layout but I'm not sure. I couldn't find any help on the Web.

**My main problem is that I don't know if it's the good approach !**

Please give me any keywords or hints that could put me on the good way !

Thanks a lot,

Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

1. Make a saperate layout which having your layout with 12 button.

suppose the name of the layout xml file is keypad.xml

1. now in any other layout where ever you want your keypad layout do this

   < include
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         layout="@layout/keypad" />

this will include your keypad layout to any layout you want.

Let me know if it is helpful for you

Comment: That's almost what I need ! I also need to implement some code behind the keypad (like OnCLickListeners, etc.), I think I might do it with a custom class that I link to the layout in my Activity.

I thought that I could do it in one shot with the XML part and the Java part already linked together. I don't know if I'm clear and I think that I don't understand Android enough for writing it down. Anyway, that was helpful, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in both the ways what ever suits you. here is an example

the first code of sample is for your activity

```
Button keypad1_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.key1_button);

keypad1_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myMethod(v);
    }
});
```

//your method which should invoke on button press event

```
public void  myMethod(View v) {
    // write your logic here
}
```

the second way is you directly write it in your xml file to invoke the myMethod(v)

here is the code:
in yout keypad.xml layout suppose you have a button

```
< Button
                        android:id="@+id/key1_button"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
                        android:text="KEY 1"
                        android:onClick="myMethod"
                        />
```

both of this methods will work. Try it